# How do I make a bash alias that outputs file names in a format I can pipe to vim?

Tags: bash, pipe, alias

When rebasing with git, I'm interested to open the files that have merge conflicts.

I can do this with:

```
vi `git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | awk '{print $2}'`
```

but if I alias that:

```
alias gdn="vi $(git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | awk '{print $2}')"
```

It won't work.  I've also tried to write this as a function, to no avail.

What is the correct syntax?

---

**edit:** this answer seems to predicate on the difference between how aliases handle newlines, vs. how the prompt handles them.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something?  Why don’t you just define the alias to be the command?

```
alias gdn="vi `git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | awk '{print $2}'`"
```

or

```
alias gdn="vi $(git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | awk '{print $2}')"
```

(You don’t need to have the `;` at the end.)

Comment: These don't work, as vim will only open the first file in a return of multiple files.

Comment: @NewAlexandria: vim will hold all arguments in args, try running `:args`. @Scott: this will not work as the backticks get evaluated when the alias is defined.

Comment: I have found that the newlines in the result were killing the input.  I used `tr` as per my self-answer, here.

Comment: @Thor: D’oh!  Another reason to use `$(…)` rather than backticks.  Thanks.

Comment: @Scott: not exactly, `$(...)` is also evaluated within double-quotes, you need to swap single and double quotes and quote `$` in the awk script.

Comment: @Thor: So maybe ***that’s*** (part of) the reason why the solution cited in the question doesn’t work.  (Doesn’t explain why the one in the OP’s answer _does_ work, though.)

Comment: Scott and @NewAlexandria: the OP's answer has the same issue as yours, the alias gets evaluated upon definition, i.e. the file names that the git command expands to become part of the alias definition.

Answer (score 1):

This works here:

```
alias gdn='vim $(git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | awk "{print \$2}")'
```

You may want to use `cut` instead of awk:

```
alias gdn='vim $(git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | cut -f2)'
```

Note, this will not work with filenames that have whitespace in them.

Answer (score -1):

I found that **aliases/functions** handle results with newlines in a different way than the **prompt**.

The only solution I found to work is to replace the newlines with spaces.  [There are many solutions to that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n), but I found `tr` to be the most succinct for this job:

```
alias gdn="vim $(git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U | cut -f2 | tr '\n' ' ' )"
```

That alias was useful for editing merge conflicts when using `git rebase`.  If you wanted to open the files that `git status` has marked modified:

```
alias gsm="vim $(git status --porcelain | cut -f2 -s -d 'M' | tr '\n' ' ' )"
```

`M` is only one of the change options for `git`, [see the full list here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html#_short_format).